# Simplifying several onclicklisteners intended to invoke the same action

Tags: java, android, iteration

I have a very simple question, I'm very new to Java so apologies if it's a trivial matter.

In one situation in my application, you get the same number of points for checking each of a series of CheckBoxes. I could set an OnClickListener for each, but this seems like an inelegant solution, so instead I'd like to write some code that says, "checking any of these CheckBoxes produces the same outcome."

What I've written unfortunately doesn't work:

```
int[] ids = {R.id.cmCheckBox1, R.id.cmCheckBox2, R.id.cmCheckBox3, R.id.cmCheckBox4, R.id.cmCheckBox5, R.id.cmCheckBox6, R.id.ctCheckBox1, R.id.ctCheckBox2, R.id.ctCheckBox3};
final CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[ids.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    checkBoxes[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids[i]);
    checkBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
                Global.score += 5;
            } else {
                Global.score -= 5;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For this code, I get the error message:

```
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable i in an inner class defined in a different method".
```

Turning line 3 into `for (final int i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {` doesn't help, I guess because a final variable cannot be modified?

Any suggestions would be most gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making anonymous classes inside a for loop, that is not really what you want to be doing.

Make your own class that implements OnClickListener, then attach it as a listener to all of your checkboxes.

Edit: since you seem to be having some trouble, here's a nudge in the right direction -

```
checkBoxes[i].setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(checkBoxes[i]));

...

class MyOnClickListener
    implements OnClickListener
{
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    public MyOnClickListener( CheckBox box )
    {
        // maintain a reference to the CheckBox so we can see if it's checked!
        this.checkBox = box; 
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // if this.checkBox is checked, then...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I can fix that. Is there any particular reason why it is not a good idea to use anonymous classes? Is it because they can then be referenced from other parts of the program, or just readability?

Comment: The biggest cost is code maintainability and readability, yes.  Plus in this case ends up not being flexible enough since you need to give your listener implementation a reference to the checkbox so it can know if it's checked or not.

Comment: I added an example since you seem to be struggling with how to reference the checkbox from within your listener.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your onClickListener can't refer to i.  The solution is to add a constructor to your onClickListener, add have that constructor take the value for i and save it to a member variable of the onClickListener.  Of course with that much code you probably want to make it a named class rather than an annonymous one for readability.

Comment: Many thanks Gabe, I'm sure this is very simple stuff, but could you give me an example of how to use a constructor to take the value of i?